# Is it possible to run a bash script from Firefox? (Using Firefox add-on SDK)

Tags: javascript, bash, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm trying to create a Firefox add-on that can automatically run bash commands when you click on a specific button. (Client Side always)

For now I managed how to execute simple commands like `ls` using:

```
var child_process = require("sdk/system/child_process");

var ls = child_process.spawn('/bin/ls', ['-lh', '/usr']);
```

My question is, can I run bash scripts? (.sh files)

for example:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
STRING="HELLO WORLD!!!"
echo $STRING
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is! Pretty easy.

```
var bash = child_process.spawn('/bin/sh', ['pathtobashscript']);
```

Comment: What if I want to press a button on a regular html page (inside the data folder of the firefox extension) and trigger the execution of the bash? Is that possible?

Comment: You can use [page-mod](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod). Just put the url you want to link to. In your case, to get the link to your local html you should call require("sdk/self").data.url(page) and pass it to the "include" argument. In the content script, add the listener to the button and when somebody clicks the button, emit the event like self.port.emit("trigger") and in the pageMod you should have the onAttach function where you should have worker.port.on("trigger", func). Read the documentation about page-mod I posted. It is clearly explained.

Comment: Can you provide an example on fiddle (or another page)? Just a basic example with the skeleton of the code. Html page A have a button in client side, if some user press the button a function inside the index.js of the firefox extension is executed.

I was reading about page-mod few days ago but...seems a little bit confusing. I'm quite new using JavaScript and it's my very first time with Firefox SDK. I would greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/tDannLca) Hope this helps. If you already have a script (like for example index.js) pass that name instead of "contentScript.js" and put the "self.port.emit("bash")" inside of the click callback.

Comment: Thank you so much! You are using jQuery right?
If i'm using only pageA.html and index.js can I delete this? `contentScriptFile: data.url("contentScript.js")` I mean the JavaScript code is inside pageA.html using `<script></script>`

Comment: You can't. Don't attach index.js within your html document. Attach it via contentScriptFile (it will do pretty the same stuff). Answering your question, I know jQuery and I use it from time to time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110554/discussion-between-gera-and-jakub-rozek).